# whats wrong with my UPDATE SQL Statement Java

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

```
String insert = "UPDATE PPN_WORKFLOW SET P1_F_Date = ?, SET P1_Completed = ?, SET C2_S_Date = ? WHERE ERF_No = ?";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            stmt.setDate(1, date);
            stmt.setInt(2, 1);
            stmt.setDate(3, date);
            stmt.setInt(4, erf_no);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I am trying to update a statement, but I am recieving this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3148)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:215)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:137)
at Mails.MailtoERF.check(MailtoERF.java:60)
at Mails.MailtoERF.main(MailtoERF.java:122)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need `SET` for each column:

[**MySQL UPDATE SYNTAX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

String insert = "UPDATE PPN_WORKFLOW SET P1_F_Date = ?, P1_Completed = ?,  
C2_S_Date = ? WHERE ERF_No = ?";
```

Answer (score 3):

you can not set like that .you need to change syntax.One time SET is enough

```
UPDATE PPN_WORKFLOW SET P1_F_Date = ?, P1_Completed = ?..... where condition
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a `SET` for each Column name, you need to separate columns with comma only and use `SET` only once, see syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql Update statement syntax is wrong.Do put `'SET' for each column in the query, you only do it at the first column`

**change it to**

```
String insert = "UPDATE PPN_WORKFLOW SET P1_F_Date = ?, P1_Completed = ?, C2_S_Date = ? WHERE ERF_No = ?";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            stmt.setDate(1, date);
            stmt.setInt(2, 1);
            stmt.setDate(3, date);
            stmt.setInt(4, erf_no);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Heres the [syntax for you reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)